# Design for Spring Framework Web Service Call

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am using Spring Framework to build my first web application right now. My current requirement is to build a web page, that if I input a customer ID and hit search button, it would return customer detail information on the same page. The customer detail info can be retrieved via 3 different web service calls. Each web service call may last for about 10 seconds, as it needs to go to Mainframe to retrieve some specific customer data.

If these 3 web services are grouped in one call, then I need to wait about 30 seconds to see the web page populated with all the required customer data.

Is it possible to do it this way? Calling the 1st web service, populating the web page with 1st part of customer data, and then calling the 2nd web service, populating the same web page with the 2nd part of customer data...In this way, after 10 seconds I hit the search button, I am able to see some customer data showing up on the web page, I don't need to wait 30 seconds.

I am new to Spring. If it is possible to make it, could you please show me some sample code? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You must show your effort. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You can go with the idea even further. Make the 3 calls in parallel then it would return the customer details after 10 seconds, depending which is the longest call

Comment: @sfat, thank you very much. That is what I am thinking about right now.